# ¿Como guardar Imágenes en mi pictureBox? C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, picturebox

Quiero que mi picturebox remplace la imagen que tiene por defecto a una que el usuario le ingresara de forma manual, actualmente tengo una linea de codigo que debería guardar la nueva imagen, pero me sale un pequeño error:

```
el nombre ImageFormat no existe en el contexto actual.
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
picFebChange.Image.Save(@"C:\Users\David\Downloads\Presupuesto_Da\Imagenes\prueba.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

> Actualizacion

Actualmente me almacena la imagen dentro de mi picturebox, pero solo mientras estoy en la ventana, una vez que salga de la ventana esta imagen desaparece y no se a que se deba esto, yo quisiera que siempre se viera mi nueva imagen en el picturebox a menos que la vuelva a cambiar.

Comment: Hola David, no he tenido la oportunidad de trabajar con `PictureBox` pero según [esta respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14028345/3200493) en SO en inglés recomienda guardarla por medio del `MemoryStream`. Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Okay, voy a ver ese post que me has pasado

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver el problema de contexto del ImageFormat solo deberias validar que defines el using que requiere

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```

de esta forma detectara la clase

Para cargar la imagen cuando abres el form nuevamente solo debes asignar nuevamente la imagen en el evento Load del form

```
public void Form1_load(...){

    string imgPath = @"C:\Users\David\Downloads\Presupuesto_Da\Imagenes\prueba.jpg";
    picFebChange.Image = Image.FromFile(imgPath);

}
```

por supuesto alli no agregue validaciones que verifican si la imagen existe como tampoco use el [Application.StartupPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx) para determinar una ruta relativa al .exe en lugar de una ruta fija

Answer (score 0):

Crear tu picturebox, seleccionas la flecha pequeña, elegir imagen, importar, y aquí puedes seleccionar las imágenes que quieras(se guardaran dentro del picturebox).

Si quieres que cambien cada vez que seleccionan un boton, solo creas el botón y dentro del código del botón insertas esto.

```
pictureBox1.Image = pictureboxpro.Properties.Resources.otono;
```

pictureBox1, es el nombre del picturebox. pictureboxpro, es el namespace. otono, es la imagen que tiene.

Solo cambia eso e inserta en diferentes botones(con diferentes imagenes) y cada que presionen los botones cambiaran las imágenes en un picturebox.